# Equal Opportunities Button

Tags: buttons, text, conversion, wording

I'm currently designing a form at the end of an application process to ask potential candidates to complete an Equal Opportunities form. (We are required by law to provide this)

However I'm trying to decide upon the best wording for the button to show them this form, after having already completed a medium length application.

Obviously we want them to complete the form, but so far the button says 'Complete Equal Opportunities Form' which I can't imagine will inspire people.

What could I replace that with, or maybe some text to convince them it's worthwhile?

Comment: Why do you need a button? Could you perhaps present the form itself but explain that it is optional?

Comment: If it is "required by law", one would wonder you will need to use the terminology used by "law" in this context.

Comment: We are required to provide it, but they aren't required to fill it out.

Comment: @MattObee I'm hoping to use the button wording to convince them to use it as it surrounded by poor legal language.

Comment: What are you exactly required to do by law - declare possibility to complete form, display form, etc.? Maybe requirement in law itself contains required wording to provide the form for candidates?

Comment: The requirement is to provide them with a form to complete, it's completely optional on their part. I'm struggling to find a way to make it seem worthwhile on their part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explaination does not have to be entierly on a button, I imagine. So I took the liberty of "borrowing" the style of Stackexchange *OK-Button-and-Cancel-link* style just below the informative persuasive text block. The idea is to have the text short enough to read, but long enough to make users wanting to fill in the form. The text is just an example and can probably be worded better since English isn't my native language.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flAFJz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Hopefully this "thinking-outside-of-the-box" answer makes you widen the design scope a little.

Good Luck!

Comment: Fantastic idea, I will look into this way of doing it!

Comment: I would prefer "skip this" instead of "cancel," as the latter may be misinterpreted to mean that the user's application will be canceled, rather than merely the equal opportunities form.